# Tree Structures: Sentence breaks and TP vs. S as tree structure head

Tags: syntax, syntax-trees

I am currently working on my Linguistics homework and I have to draw a tree diagram of the sentences:
(1) Peter thinks Susan asked if she needs to resign.
(2) Johnny said he wants to study French.

The sentence (1) Is currently the on making the most trouble for me since I don't really know how to deal with both the sentence break between thinks and Susan and the if. I first considered if as I PP but then I would miss an NP to go along with that and instead have two VP in that last part but I'm honestly not really sure if or how that would work out.

The sentence (2) is troublesome because in my current Seminar we use TPs as a head for the sentence while in the seminar where I learned how to draw tree diagrams we used S as the head of the sentence and used TP later in the structure tree. With that in mind, I would be needing a different Phrase for 'wants to study French'.
If anyone could help me with the tree structure diagrams that would be amazing and if someone could give me a short explanation for why the tree diagram ends up the way it does I would appreciate that even more.

Comment: What textbook are you using now?

Comment: Radford, Andrew (2009) An Introduction to English Sentence Structure. Cambridge:
Cambridge University Press.

Comment: re sentence (1): section 2.4 Clauses containing complementisers

Comment: also take a look at example (51a) and its tree structure (51b) on p. 100 - this should help.

Comment: After looking at the sections in the book pointed out I have finished this structure for sentence (1):
[S[NP[N'[N Peter]]][VP[V'[V thinks][CP[C' [NP[N'[N Susan]]][VP[V'[V asked][CP[PP[P'[P if][NP[N'[N she]]]]][VP [V'[V needs][PP[P'[P to][VP[V'[V resign]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]

Is this in any way correct?

Comment: "in my current Seminar we use TPs as a head for the sentence " - TP perhaps instead of your S then?

Comment: First of all, I did not realize that I wrote S but I will change that secondly, I tried my luck with sentence (2):  [TP[N John][T'[T said][CP[NP[N he]][VP[V'[V wants][PP[P'[P to][CP[VP[V study]][NP[N french]]]]]]]]]]  I just hope this is somewhat ok I did use TP as head this time

Comment: wants to study and needs to resign: see example (9) in your book, p. 41, or example (11) on p. 42

Comment: Tree diagrams are not permitted here. Please read the Guide.